# How to create a user using visualforce page and controller?

Tags: visualforce

How to create a user using visualforce page and create a form with 6 user fields and fill remaining fields in  controller when i click submit button new user should be created?

Comment: Welcome to the community. You'll find that to get the best answers to your questions if you provide us with what you've tried so far and where you are stuck. Asking for someone to do your work for you won't get you the help that will assist you in learning the Salesforce platform further.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking a look at the standard system-generated Salesforce code for basic business cases like these. Here is a self-reg page we built from a standard Communities page, I stripped down some extra functionality that we added so let me know if there are any errors.

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page id="communitiesSelfRegPage" showHeader="true" controller="CommunitiesSelfRegController" title="Register">

     <apex:define name="body">  
     <center>
     <apex:form id="theForm" forceSSL="true">
                    <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
                    <h3>Note: all fields are required.</h3>
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="First Name" for="firstName"/>
                    <apex:inputText required="true" id="firstName" value="{!firstName}" label="First Name"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Last Name" for="lastName"/>
                    <apex:inputText required="true" id="lastName" value="{!lastName}" label="Last Name"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Community Nickname" for="communityNickname"/>
                    <apex:inputText required="true" id="communityNickname" value="{!communityNickname}" label="Community Nickname"/>

                    <apex:outputLabel value="Company" for="company"/>
                    <apex:inputText required="true" id="company" value="{!company}" label="Company"/>

                    <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="email"/>
                    <apex:inputText required="true" id="email" value="{!email}" label="Email}"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Password" for="password"/>
                    <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Confirm Password" for="confirmPassword"/>
                    <apex:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" value="{!confirmPassword}"/>
                    <apex:outputText value=""/>

                    <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" value="Submit" id="submit" disabled="true" />
                    </apex:panelGrid>
                    <br/>
     </apex:form>
     </center>
     <br/>
     </apex:define>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class CommunitiesSelfRegController {

    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String company {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }

    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {}

    private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }



    public PageReference registerUser() {

           // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
        if (!isValidPassword()) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        }    

        String profileId = null; // To be filled in by customer.
        String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
        String accountId = ''; // To be filled in by customer.

        String userName = email;

        User u = new User();
        u.Username = userName;
        u.Email = email;
        u.FirstName = firstName;
        u.LastName = lastName;
        u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
        u.ProfileId = profileId;
        u.CompanyName = company;

        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);

        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(userName, password, null);
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `$Label.` references will cause a compilation error

Comment: You're right! I'll explicitly add them here to standalone